# Apex - List findIndex

Tags: apex, list, find

How can I do like findIndex from List in Apex?

I wanna do like below.

```java
public class SelectItem {
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

public void FooMethod() {
    List<SelectItem> itemList = new List<SelectItem>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.Text = 'test' + String.valueOf(i);
        item.Value = String.valueOf(i);
        itemList.add(item);
    }
    
    // I wanna do↓
    Integer targetIndex = itemList.findIndex(x => x.Text == 'test2');
    SelectItem targetItem = itemList[targetIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrow functions don't exist in Apex. This is plain JavaScript.

You can conceptually find an element if you already have it:

```
SelectOption[] options = 
    new SelectOption[] {
    new SelectOption('a','a'),
    new SelectOption('b','b')
};
SelectOption target = new SelectOption('b','b');
System.assertEquals(1, options.indexOf(target));
```

This operation is basically dependent on all fields being the same. In other cases, you probably won't be able to use this; you'll need to come up with a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use the same (partial match) criteria for finding values (here you match the Text value), the best solution is to actually use a Map not a List. Something like this:

```
public class SelectItem {
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

public void FooMethod() {
    Map<String, SelectItem> items = new Map<String, SelectItem>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.Text = 'test' + String.valueOf(i);
        item.Value = String.valueOf(i);
        items.put(item.Text, item);
    }
    
    // targetItem will be null when no item exists with the given Text value
    SelectItem targetItem = items.get('test2');
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to use different criteria in different scenarios you can only do this by introducing specific logic, for example:

```
public class SelectItem {
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

public void FooMethod() {
    List<SelectItem> itemList = new List<SelectItem>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.Text = 'test' + String.valueOf(i);
        item.Value = String.valueOf(i);
        itemList.add(item);
    }
    
    // Remember targetIndex could be -1 if there's no match
    Integer targetIndex = findIndexByText(itemList, 'test2');
    SelectItem targetItem = itemList[targetIndex];
}

private Integer findIndexByText(List<SelectItem> items, String textToMatch) {
    for (Integer index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {
        if (items[index].Text == textToMatch) {
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

// Other implementations on other criteria
private Integer findIndexByValue(...) { ... }
```

It is even possible to write a more generic mechanism, something like:

```
public interface Matcher {
    Boolean matches(Object item, Object value);
}

public Integer findIndex(List<Object> items, Object value, Matcher matcher) {
    for (Integer index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {
        if (matcher.matches(items[index], value) {
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

You then have to provide implementations of the Matcher interface though, so perhaps:

```
public class SelectItem {
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

public void FooMethod() {
    List<SelectItem> itemList = new List<SelectItem>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.Text = 'test' + String.valueOf(i);
        item.Value = String.valueOf(i);
        itemList.add(item);
    }
    
    // Again targetIndex could be -1 where there is no match
    Integer targetIndex = findIndex(itemList, new TextMatcher(), 'test2');
    SelectItem targetItem = itemList[targetIndex];
}

private class TextMatcher implements Matcher {
    public Boolean matches(Object item, Object value) {
        return item instanceof SelectItem && value instanceof String &&
            ((SelectItem) item).Text == ((String) value);
    }
}
```

That said, the latter solution is complete overkill in general terms since it adds so much code just to lift the looping and index tracking into something generic.